# OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: No more data to read. Deserializing page header failed

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I am fetching data from event hub and uploading it to blob with blob_type `AppendBlob` it appending correctly but when i download and try to read that parquet file then it showing this error `OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: No more data to read. Deserializing page header failed.` and sometime this error also `Unexpected end of stream: Page was smaller (4) than expected (13)` could anyone help me in understanding both error and help me in solving former error.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import (BlobCheckpointStore)

EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR = ""
EVENT_HUB_NAME = ""
BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = ""
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = ""

async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    global finalDF
    try:
       
        data = event.body_as_json(encoding='UTF-8')
        df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=[0])
        finalDF=pd.concat([finalDF,df])
       
        if finalDF.shape[0]>100:
            uniqueBPIds=(finalDF['batteryserialnumber'].unique()).tolist()
            parquet = BytesIO()
            for i in uniqueBPIds:
                tempdf=finalDF[finalDF['batteryserialnumber']==i]
                tempdf.to_parquet(parquet)
                parquet.seek(0)
                blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
                blob_path = f'new8_{year}/{month}/{i}/{i}_{year}_{month}_{day}.parquet'
                blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME, blob=blob_path)
                blob_client.upload_blob(data = parquet,overwrite=False,blob_type='AppendBlob')
            finalDF=pd.DataFrame()
            print('done')
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR',e)

    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)
    
async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(
        BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME
    )

    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,
        eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME,
    )
    async with client:
        await client.receive(on_event=on_event, starting_position="-1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k=0
    finalDF = pd.DataFrame()
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    year, month, day = current_datetime.year, current_datetime.month, current_datetime.day

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: How are you storing event data in the Azure blob storage? Is it in text file for each event?

Comment: Have you checked this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal) for receiving events from event hubs?

Comment: storing in parquet form appending each event in same parquet file. @Dasari Kamali

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below to store each event from the Event Hub namespace to Azure blob storage in individual parquet files.

**Code :**

```py
import datetime
import json
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import uuid
import io


def on_event(partition_context, event):
    event_data = json.loads(event.body_as_str())
    print(f"Event Received from Partition {partition_context.partition_id}: {event_data}")
    save_event_to_blob(event_data, partition_context.partition_id)
    partition_context.update_checkpoint()

def on_error(partition_context, error):
    print(f"Error Received: {error}")

def save_event_to_blob(event_data, partition_id):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
        "<storage_conne_string>"
    )
    container_name = "<container_name>"
    blob_name = f"{datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}-{uuid.uuid4()}.parquet"

    blob_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    if not blob_container_client.exists():
        blob_container_client.create_container()

    blob_client = blob_container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

    with io.BytesIO(json.dumps(event_data).encode('utf-8')) as stream:
        blob_client.upload_blob(stream, overwrite=True)

    print(f"Event stored in blob: {blob_name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventhub_namespace = "<eventhub_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net"
    eventhub_name = "<eventhub_name>"
    connection_str = f"Endpoint=sb://{eventhub_namespace}/;SharedAccessKeyName=kamc;SharedAccessKey=<event_key>;EntityPath={eventhub_name}"

    consumer_client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        connection_str,
        consumer_group="$Default",
    )

    consumer_client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        on_error=on_error,
        starting_position="-1",  
    )
```

**Output :**

The code ran successfully, as shown below:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx>python -u "c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx\sample.py"

Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 0, 'Message': 'This is event 0'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 1, 'Message': 'This is event 1'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 2, 'Message': 'This is event 2'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 3, 'Message': 'This is event 3'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 4, 'Message': 'This is event 4'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 5, 'Message': 'This is event 5'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 6, 'Message': 'This is event 6'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 7, 'Message': 'This is event 7'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 8, 'Message': 'This is event 8'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxx.parquet
Event Received from Partition 0: {'EventId': 9, 'Message': 'This is event 9'}
Event stored in blob: 2024-01-20-xxxxxxx.parquet
```

[image]

**Azure Portal :**

All events were stored in their respective parquet files, as demonstrated below:

[image]

Each event data was saved to its corresponding parquet file, as illustrated below.

[image]

Comment: instead of storing individual parquet file can you try to append each events into existing file for that you can use
`blob_client.upload_blob(stream, overwrite=False,blob_type='AppendBlob'). @Dasari Kamali